# what is the process of reading message from device message app using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, android-messaging

I made a flutter app for storing message. Now I want to read the message from the device message box and show it in a window using flutter how can i do that

it would be better if i can get name of a package to do so or the process of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

it think this package can help you with what you want . it gives you access to read device sms box .you can also get messages of a specific number with help of it's recipents argument which get a list of numbers which you want to access in string .

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the telephony package for Android.
Add the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml,
You can access your SMS data with the telephony.getInboxSms() method.
for detail => `https://telephony.shounakmulay.dev/query-sms`